# Jsf application and polymer web components

Tags: java, polymer

I have sample java web application with JSF 2.1. Can I use polymer custom web components in jsf application? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Polymer can be included in your view (xhtml site), since it's frontend library. Do not however expect any interoperability with backing beans other whan inserting values. You need a JSF Tag library like PrimeFaces to expect such behaviour.

Comment: Do you maybe have any source-links to add?

Answer (score 0):

you can use polymer with passsthough elements (jsf 2.2) , by the way , if you use passsthough elements in your pages, you improve the performance of your application.